# PHP + MySQL - transactions dont rollback

Tags: php, mysql, sqltransaction

I am using old-style `mysql_query()` functions to perform a transaction. It is not rolling back even though one of the queries in the transaction has failed. I have debugged affected rows and they are either 0 or 1. Syntax followed:

```
 $cnx = mysql_connect( .. ); 
 mysql_select_db("DB", $cnx); 
 mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
 mysql_query("BEGIN");

 $isrollback = -1; 

 for (...) // run through query list 
 {
    mysql_query(".... query_i ....");
    if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0) 
    {
          $isrollback = 1
    }

 }

 // more queries 
 if ($isrollback > 0) 
     mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
 else
     mysql_query("COMMIT);
```

Comment: What DB Engine are you using? if its MyISAM then it does not support transactions

Comment: `mysql_affected_rows` => `Returns the number of affected rows on success, and -1 if the last query failed`

Comment: You don't need to start the transaction 2 times ;)

Comment: redreggae is true. sorry but this is really shows no effort to debug your own code! -1

Comment: i tried `if (mysql_affected_rows() <= 0)` and it still doesnt help

Comment: I have debugged `mysql_affected_rows()` and they are either 0 or 1

Comment: You didn't answer which engine are you using??

Comment: you see it under `index.php?db=YOUR_DB` and the column `Type`

Comment: Just checked MyISAM - this is ridiculous. DB transactions have been around since 70s I thought. How old is MyISAM??!?!

Comment: MyISAM is build on ISAM which was developed in the late 60's ;)

Comment: Innodb has been around for years and does support transactions, just change to using a transactional DB engine instead of one that is non transactional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a transactional database engine. eg INNODB

You are currently using MyISAM which does not support transactions.

This means you cannot start or rollback transactions without changing your DB engine.

MySQL gives instructions on how to convert from [MyISAM to INNODB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html)